# How does ArrayList implementation work in Java at the lowest level?

Tags: java

I was trying to figure out how is it that you can add objects of the subclass to an ArrayList of type superclass.

Ex SavingsAccount extends Account. 
You have an arrayList of type Account.
You can add an object of SavingsAccount to the arrayList.

If ArrayList uses array as the underlying implementation then it needs to know the type of the data that will be stored in the array so that it can partition the memory block into the correct number of bytes that each object will occupy. Now let's say an Account object uses 8 bytes, but a SavingsAccount object uses 16 bytes. I'm assuming that the underlying array will be partioned into 8 byte slots so how can it fit a 16 byte object into the 8 byte slot? I'm confused.

Comment: Removing generics from the picture, `ArrayList` is backed by a `Object` array, meaning you could add any `Object` to it.  Generics provides a compile time checking feature that allows you to essentially apply a "filter" to the `ArrayList` to restrict it so it will only allow a given type of `Object` (`Account`) to be added to the list, since `SavingsAccount` is a type of `Account` (and if the generics were setup correctly), then you'd be able to add an instance of `SavingsAccount` to the `ArrayList`, but the `ArrayList` would only see it as a type of `Account`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ArrayList will only contain pointers to your object. So no matter what size your object is, since your List will only contain list of references to it, size of object does not matter.

Answer (score 3):

An array of objects in Java does not have a solid block of memory where all objects in the array are allocated. Rather, it has a block of object *references*, usually implemented as pointers to the objects. The objects live somewhere else. No matter what type of object a reference refers to, the reference takes the same amount of space.